# Do you create a service to share a single function between components?

Tags: angular, design-patterns

When I have a single function that isn't part of a collection of functions that serve the same purpose I don't bother creating a Service for it.

I just have a separate helper.ts file that holds those functions.

I was just wondering how others solve that problem

Comment: i would do the same except i would name the file differently. in your example `helper.functions.ts`.
also `helper` says nothing about it. it would probably be better to name the file `product.functions.ts` for example

Comment: ahh great tip, Thanks!